# Python setup.py develop stuck at "writing dependency_links"

Tags: python, setuptools

I am trying to run `python setup.py develop` on a package that contains some helper scripts.

The package is structured as follows:

```
mytools
|--mytools
|--tests
|--notebooks
|--xxx
|--yyy
|--zzz
```

The `setup.py` file is as follows:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='mytools',
    version='0.0.1',
    packages=['mytools'],
)
```

Running `python setup.py develop` produces the following output:

```
running develop
running egg_info
writing mytools.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to mytools.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to mytools.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
```

The problem is that the build appears to hang at the last line. It is doing a lot of I/O, but I don't know why? **Some of the other folders in the package root directory (i.e. `tests`, `notebooks`, `xxx`, `yyy`, `zzz`) contain many small and big files**, but I don't want the install script to think about them (hence `packages=['mytools']`).

Any suggestions?

**Edit:**

1) Versions:

```
Python: 3.5.1
setuptools: 23.0.0
```

2) After moving all subfolders except `mytools`, `python setup.py develop` works as expected. However, I would like to keep everything in one place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in [setuptools](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools) (see [#249](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/249), [#450](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/450)).

`setuptools` would first create a list of all files in the project directory, and would then filter that list to only include files specified in `packages`, `package_data`, `MANIFEST.in`, etc.

This has been addressed with pull requests [#610](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/pull/610) and [#764](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/pull/764), and as of `setuptools==28.5.0` is no longer a problem.